# Get 2714 during msi install

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I get error 2714 when I try to install one of my projects.

[image]

Created a simple project where I can create and run the installer successfully. The msi log from the successful and failed setups are the same till the following line, which is in the failed setup:

```
...
line 100 - MSI (c) (38:10) [08:02:30:371]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ROOTDRIVE property. Its value is 'd:\'.
line 101 - MSI (c) (38:10) [08:02:30:371]: Note: 1: 2714 2: ./|./ 
line 102 - MSI (c) (38:10) [08:02:30:371]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
line 103 - DEBUG: Error 2714:  Invalid value for default folder name: ./|./.
line 104 - MSI (c) (38:48) [08:02:30:374]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
...
```

The strange error which probably causes the installer to fail is in the line 101.

**My project structure**

- MyApp.ConsoleApp(Console app)
- MyApp.Core(Class library)
- MyApp.Tests(MS Test project)
- MyApp.UI(C# WPF app)
- Setup(The setup project)

Based on [Windows installer error messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-error-messages),

The 2714 error is:

```
2714 - Invalid value for default folder name: [2].
```

Used the following command to get more info from the error

```
msiexec /i Setup.msi /L*V info.log
```

What could I do to get more info where that "./|./ " -probably- path comes from in?

Did anyone face similar issue and solved it?

Comment: I still couldn't figure out what was the error, but I managed to build a nice installer with WiX, instead of visual studio setup project.